# Is it possible to hide many rows of a Google spreadsheet at once?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm using this script below (credit: Eduardo Kuwakino).
The problem I have that it hides the rows from column A:A with the value "x" one by one.
Is it possible to make this "less painful" for the people who are editing these spreadsheets?

```
function hideCells(sheet)
{
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from clumn A
  var data = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if asterisk, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == 'x'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }}

function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for(var i=0; i< sheets.length; i++){

      hideCells(sheets[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a method [hideRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows) which can hide several rows at once, but they must be **consecutive**. In your situation, the rows will not be consecutive in general. So script has to hide them one by one (or maybe in groups when a few happen to be together, but I don't think this will help much). And indeed, this will be slow in a large sheet.

As an alternative, I suggest using a [filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en), specifically filter the sheet by the column A with custom formula `=A2<>"x"`

[image: filter view]

Each filter view has its own URL, which can be sent to people editing the spreadsheet. They will see only the rows where the value in A is different from "x".